# Редирект сайта с http://site . http://www.site на https://site

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

подскажите, как сделать редирект :
Дано: 
http://site
http://www.site

Нужно получить 
https://site

У меня сейчас идёт переадресация при http://www.site на https://www.site а нужно что бы сразу на https://site

Comment: В справке советуют: "Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа." и, судя по тому, что вы создали новый вопрос, тщательный поиск не был выполнен https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+www

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, дело было в том что с начала нужно писать правила редиректа с www на без www а после уже редиректить на https:// .

Comment: Ваш ответ был бы более полезным, если бы вы добавили соответствующие инструкции .htaccess